# JIRA REST API issue transitions and worklog (v4.4.1)

Tags: jira

Is it possible to update the worklog for an issue when transitioning (i.e. POST to /rest/api/latest/issue/{issueid}/transitions) via the REST API for JIRA (API version is 2.0.alpha1 of JIRA v4.4.1)? I'm posting a `worklog` as part of the request and looking for the minimum information I need to send (currently just `minutesSpent` and `started` time as these seem to be the only mandatory ones via the UI).

i.e.

```
worklog:
{
    name: "worklog",
    type: "worklog",
    value: [
    {
        started: "2012-10-01T10:28:00.000+1000",
        minutesSpent: 480
    }
    ]
},
```

Currently the post to the URL seems to just ignore this additional data although the transition does take effect with a desired 204 response.

Comment: In the mean time I've used the SOAP API for this portion of my integration.

Comment: Which syntax did you used for SOAP API Worklog??

Answer (score 2):

From the [JIRA REST API Docs](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id251752):

The fields that can be set on transtion, in either the fields parameter or the update parameter can be determined using the **/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields** resource. If a field is not configured to appear on the transition screen, then it will not be in the transition metadata, and a field validation error will occur if it is submitted.

If, in the response you get from the expansion, you don't see worklog, then I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this initially (without the expand option but it doesn't seem to have an affect on the above API version). Worklog is in the response, teasing that it is possible in some way.